# Connection Failed CakePHP 3 and MSSQL on Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, cakephp

I'm trying to connect a new project `CakePHP v3` installed in a common LAMP on Ubuntu Server and the DataBase is a `MSSQL 2008`. I've tried to install the library `php5-mssql` but nothing changes. Any idea?

The error message received is:
`CakePHP` is NOT able to connect to the DataBase.

DataBase driver `Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver` cannot be used due to a missing `PHP` extension or unmet dependency

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP does not have an ODBC driver at this time. You can connect to MSSQL servers using the SQLServer driver from a Windows server, but this issue (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6990 ) just keeps getting bumped.

Answer (score -1):

Since Cake3 uses PDO drivers to connect SQL Server (from Linux), you should try to install Microsoft ODBC Driver for Linux, see

http://onefinepub.com/2013/03/ms-sql-odbc-ubuntu/

it may helps